# RedirectToAction gets ignored

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET 5. Using the browser Chrome.

My Controller has the following Action Method

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DoSomething()
{
    //do something
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

When I run

> http://localhost:59693/MyArea/MyController/DoSomething

via a POST in Index

and have a breakpoint over the line

```cs
 return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

it just ignores the line and goes to the next line without calling the Index action method.

and displays in the browser

> http://localhost:59693/MyArea/MyController/DoSomething

with a blank screen.

Surely if you have a return statement then it immediately returns from that method and doesn't jump to the next line. Really odd.

I even tried to the full

```cs
 return RedirectToAction("Index","MyController,new {area="MyArea"});
```

When I put a breakpoint on my Index Action Method it never gets hit.

I even tried

```cs
 return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

It still displays

> http://localhost:59693/MyArea/MyController/DoSomething

Some bug in ASP.NET 5?

How to I call an action method from an action method in the same controller if the above doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show your routing configuration?

Comment: Please try different browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed my DoSomething action method to be asynchronous and added an await clause

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething()
{
    await _db.callsql();
    //do something start

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The issue seems to be because the actionmethod `Index` was asynchronous but `DoSomething` not, combined with me stepping through the code.

Comment: Figure since this was Google's top result when I searched for this same error, I'll leave that my solution was I had mine in an if statement, and changed it from a `return View()` to a `RedirectToAction("..")` and forgot to add the `return` statement!  Tired from long hours of working on my project,  and since the code still returned a path I kept over looking and missing it...